# How to complete Demolition Man on a laptop without NUMPAD?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-vice-city

In GTA Vice CIty, there is a mission called Demolition Man. To control the RC Helicopter, NUMPAD6 and NUMPAD9 are the keys to go forward and backward. Since my laptop doesnt have these keys, what should I do?

Comment: Have you tried rebinding the keys to something else through the options menu?

Comment: No, I haven't @Timelord64

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to change the controls in the control settings.

Alternatively, you can get yourself an additional keyboard with a numpad.